# Running SSH command with PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh, command, debian

I have this code

```
<?php
    $host = "MYSERVERIP";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "123456";
    $command = $_GET["command"];

    if($command != null) {
        //HERE I WANT THE PHP TO SEND THE COMMAND TO THE SERVER
    } else {
        echo"No command were given!";
    }
?>
```

Simply I want it to work like this: Let's say I go to `MYSERVERIP/sendcommand.php?command=reboot` then I want my server to reboot, how can I do this? My server is running Debian.

I've tried to understand it by reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php, but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: When you say "that dosnt get me somewhere," what do you mean? What happened when you tried using it?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to run command on the same server php runs - just use **exec** or **shell_exec**

Comment: Yeah but how do i make the connection?

Comment: connection to what?
just put **php -r "exec('ls -lah');"** in your console if you working on linux to get example

Or put it in php file..

Comment: <?php
//sendcommand.php file
if (isset($_GET['command'] && $_GET['command'] === 'reboot')) {
    exec('reboot now');
}

Answer (score 1):

ther is an example right there on your link...

mix with your stuff would look like

```
$host = "MYSERVERIP";
$user = "root";
$password = "123456";
$command = $_GET["command"];

if($command != null) {
    $connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $_GET["command"]);
} else {
    echo"No command were given!";
}
```

Assuming the server would accepts commands like this

Answer (score 0):

If your file is same server with your php file, you can use

```
exec() or shell_exec( string $cmd )
```

If Not same server, it's not possible, that all i know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to issue a command on a different server than the server that runs PHP, you need to start with [ssh2_connect](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php).

If you want to issue commands locally on the server, start out by reading about [program execution](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php).

I suggest you pay close attention to the security aspect of this.
You should also know that these two options are probably disabled if you are on a shared hosting environment.